# What causes exception 2015936646-114094 (-407009801) in deployments?

Tags: big-object

I am trying to do a deployment of a Big Object as part of this trailhead module using Workbench API 41.  I have verified that I am in the correct org.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/big_objects/big_objects_define_custom_big_objects

I have everything defined correctly.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: What you have here is a GACK. There's not much that non-Salesforce employees (i.e. 99%+ of the active community here) will be able to do with this information. Your best bet is probably to contact Salesforce Support (if you are able to) to log a case.